# Trusty - whole disc copy using sudo dd .. of=/dev/disk/by-id/xx does not write

Tags: 14.04, dd

I want to move failing hdd into spare using dd. 
All goes well usind if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdi for example, but I tried to use serial number of hdd to avoid messing the things (well the mistake would be bad).
Command run was:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST32000542AS_5XW1W057 of=/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST32000542AS_5XW200F6 bs=1M
```

But dd refuses to copy more than 4.0GB with error:

```
dd: error writing \u2018/dev/disk/by-id/ata-ST32000542AS_5XW200F6\u2019: No space left on device
3835+0 records in
3834+0 records out
4021047296 bytes (4,0 GB) copied, 155,973 s, 25,8 MB/s
```

In fact, iostat is telling me that it did not actually write anything at all.
What that \u2018 prefix and suffix does mean there, and how it comes there?
Did I miss something important about /disk/by-id/ , or is it a bug?

Comment: \u2018 and \u2019 are simply Unicode representations of left and right single quotes, respectively, and can be disregarded.

Comment: Oh, well, thanks. So it is ok, just a text formatting. But now, why it does not work.

Comment: `No space left on device` - indicates that dd is detecting a 'disk full' status. And that as 4GB has been written... (2^32 bytes) - might there be a more general malfunction than "just one disk"? Causing at least those two disks to have trouble with space beyond 4GB? If you do `ls -l /dev/disks/by*` you will see that what there is are *links*.

Comment: No sir, that is not fault of destination, and when I run the same copy of those same disks, but using if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdi, everything run well (still working as those are 2TB drives but far past 4GB). And note that iostat did say that nothing was written to /dev/sdi when used /disk/by-id/. I tried twice or thee times before giving up and started to use /dev/sdi, and now iostat shows that nicely.

Comment: ** If you do ls -l /dev/disks/by* you will see that what there is are links. ** I see one that is target of my dd, is overwritten and now it is not a link. Well, so the problem was that dd did not used the link, but started to overwrite it by data.  I guess that is my mistake and that is the key, /disk/by-id/xx can not be used with dd ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason. My mistake:

I did note disk path and prepared dd command first, and THEN moved the target disc, from sata enclosure to usb3. To avoid sharing single esata line by both data paths. That move was the reason why I tried to use id of the disc rather than some unsure /dev/sdi, thinking that id will remain same in new place...

But the physical move from esata to usb, did change /dev/disk/by-id/ of the disc completely, and past the move it was simply non-existant.

That is why dd did CREATE new file using given name, regardless of it was under directory of /dev/disk/by-id. And THE FILE was written upto 4.0GB and no space left.
ls -l is telling that all, but I would never find that without Your help.

Thank You for helping me, this error was between screen and the chair.

Comment: ... and post answer, after I run hddtemp to see temperature of all drives including USB one, which I have to run as hddtemp sata:/dev/sdi to tell it to use sata protocol, the FILE created by dd in /dev/disk/by-id simply disappeared, and there is creted a link, which is exactly as if that usb disc were at sata, exactly as the name I was using in dd command that failed. Now it shows at ls -l this: 'lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 júl 11 12:30 ata-ST32000542AS_5XW200F6 -> ../../sdi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 júl 11 10:21 usb-ST320005_42AS-0:0-part1 -> ../../sdi1'

Comment: Mark it is accepted too..